# Set html contents of an element using jQuery but with multiple elements of the same class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

As the title says, I'm trying to set the html contents of an element using jQuery. The context that I'll be using this is when a user hovers over a row on a table. While hovering a popup will display with information specific to the row. However, because the rows contain the same class jQuery's $().html() class will only display information about the first element that matches that class.

Here's the snippet of code

```
$(".row").hover(
  function() {
    $(".popup").html(
      $(".content-to-be-displayed").html()
    );
    $(".popup").show();

    $(window).on("mousemove.tooltip", function(e) {
      var x = (e.clientX + 20) + 'px',
          y = (e.clientY + 20) + 'px';
      $(".popup").css({
        top: y,
        left: x,
      });
    });
  },
  function() {
    $(".popup").hide();
    $(window).off("mousemove.tooltip");
  }
);
```

**HTML in partial**

```
<tr class= "row">
<div class="content-to-be-displayed" style="display: none;">
  <h4>Header:</h4>
  <% example_model.example.each do |example| %>
         <p>
           <%= 'erb plus html content' %>
         </p>
        <% end %>
     </div>
   </tr>
```

**HTML in template**

```
 <%= row do %>
 <thead>
 </thead>
 <tbody>
    <div class="popup"></div>
    <%= render partial: 'partial', collection: @data %>
 </tbody>
 <% end %>
```

Comment: What is your HTML like, is `.popup` a descendant of `.row`?

Comment: Can you show us your HTML?

Comment: Sorry, just added it.

Comment: Rendered HTML not templates, preferably showing at least two rows.

Comment: That html structure is invalid my friend

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a combination of $(this) and .find

Working example: https://jsfiddle.net/osvLs54L/

HTML

```
    <div class="row">
        <div class="content-to-be-displayed">
            Weee1
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="content-to-be-displayed">
            Weee2
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="content-to-be-displayed">
            Weee3
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="popup">

    </div>
```

JQuery

```
$(".row").hover(
 function() { $(".popup").html( $(this).find('.content-to-be-displayed').html());}
);
```

EDIT: Your table structure is invalid html and I am impressed your browser is even displaying much of anything. Please read here for the proper structure. https://css-tricks.com/complete-guide-table-element/

In the example you've given, just initiallity make these adjustments so it is valid (adding your content to  elements under the  elements

HTML in template

```
 <%= row do %>
 <thead>
 </thead>
 <tbody>
    <tr>
     <td>
      <div class="popup"></div>
     </td>
    </tr>

    <%= render partial: 'partial', collection: @data %>
 </tbody>
 <% end %>
```

HTML in partial

```
<tr class= "row">
 <td>
   <div class="content-to-be-displayed" style="display: none;">
    <h4>Header:</h4>
    <% example_model.example.each do |example| %>
         <p>
           <%= 'erb plus html content' %>
         </p>
     <% end %>
    </div>
 </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: I just tried this but still no luck. The popup div only displays partially and no text either. I'm assuming it's not retrieving the content that's contained within the "content-to-be-displayed" div.

Comment: @buttonSmasher96 I think that has more to do with your html being all kinds of jacked up and invalid. You can't put divs sitting directly under the tr elements. You need to restructure that to be within td or you'll continue to experience all kinds of wackiness

Comment: Would it be better to put the div outside the table? I'm not exactly sure where to put it.

Comment: You could but you are still facing the fact that you are not using <td> tags within your <tr> which is what the markeup of a table is defined by. I will modify my answer so you can get an idea of what I am talking about and let you run with it.

Comment: Thank you so much, that helped and it fixed it!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure what you are trying to do - but I'll give it a try.
Don't use separate popup elements (you can, but its not clean).
Try storing the popup data in a data attribute.

When you are using a class Selector which targets multiple elements you can refer to the current element with the `this` variable which is pointing to the actual element who triggered the event - this way you can use it to use only its attributes / childrens etc...

Here is a Quick demo: **[JSnippet Demo](https://www.jsnippet.net/snippet/1446/Making-a-simple-popup-for-tables-with-different-rows)**

HTML:

```
<table>
  <tr class="row" data-popup="Popup Row 1 Data">
    <td>Row 1</td>
    <td>Hover Me</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="row" data-popup="Popup Row 2 Data">
    <td>Row 2</td>
    <td>Hover Me</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="row" data-popup="Popup Row 3 Data">
    <td>Row 3</td>
    <td>Hover Me</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<div class="popup"></div>
```

JS:

```
$(function(){
  $(".row").hover(
    function() {
      var $this = $(this);
      $(".popup").text($this.data("popup"));
      $(".popup").css({ 
        top: $this.offset().top, 
        left:  $this.offset().left + $this.width() + 5,
        width: $this.width()
      }).show();
    },
    function() {
      $(".popup").hide();
    }
  );
});
```

Comment: This solution wouldn't work out too well because of the information contained in the div, it's a lot of erb and html